# Как поменять стандартный значок даты календаря на другой в input

Tags: html, css

```html
<input class="input" type="date" value="2023-12-05" />
```

Comment: https://freefrontend.com/css-calendars/ тут много стилей, можно тоже использовать идеи

Comment: а тут как раз, чтоб поменять инпут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436074/change-date-input-triangle-to-a-calendar-icon

Comment: мне вот это решение понравилось https://stackoverflow.com/a/45132115/13754729

Comment: Спасибо за нужную информацию!

Answer (score 3):

Можно перекрыть значок:

```css
.sd-container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.sd {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
}

.open-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.open-button button {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="sd-container">
    <input class="sd" type="date" name="selected_date" />
    <span class="open-button">
      <button type="button"></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```